# Iron-form upload image woes- work around looses other data

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Polymer 1.0

I have a form which the user fills out text fields, radio buttons, etc. They also upload photos.

Since iron-form does not support mutlipart/form-data, I am using the iron-form presubmit event feature/workaround [described here](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-form/issues/54)

```
    this.formData.addEventListener('iron-form-presubmit', ()=> {
      var bar = new FormData();
      bar.append('listingImage', this.binaryImages[0]); 
      this.formData.request.body = bar;
      this.formData.request.contentType = undefined;
    });
```

This works and I am able to successfully upload images to my server using form data. However, I loose all the other form data that would normally be in the body...the text fields, radio button selections, etc.

Is it possible with iron-form to retain existing form data and attach the images in this workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new FormData in which you add the image to and then you overwrite the original request body (formData). You should just be appending the image to the existing request body instead of creating a new one.

```
this.formData.addEventListener('iron-form-presubmit', ()=> {
  this.formData.request.body.append('listingImage', this.binaryImages[0]); 
});
```

Comment: `this.formData.append('listingImage', this.binaryImages[0]);` works without creating a new form object. but then content type is `Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8.`